# Call function from the list of array

Tags: javascript, function, arraylist, call

Can any one please help me on to call the function with argument from array. I wrote an below sample, but at the end i am getting error "**Uncaught TypeError: Property '0' of object [object Array] is not a function**"

```
function add(a, b){
    console.log("Addition: " + (a + b))
}

function sub(a, b){
    console.log("Subtraction: " + (a - b))
}

function multi(a, b){
    console.log("Multiplication: " + (a * b))
}

function div(a, b){
    console.log("Division: " + (a / b))
}

var fList = [add(1,1), sub(1,1), multi(1,1), div(1,1)];

for (var i = 0; i < fList.length; i++){
fList[i]();
}
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/k5grM/

Comment: try...window.call(fList[i]);

Comment: @Jason How will that help? `fList` is an array of numbers, not an array of functions.

Answer (score 2):

The parenthesis actually invoke the function and so when you add each one to the list it is calling it right there and then. You are really creating an array of the return values from the functions.

Answer (score 0):

You would probably want to do this as an object, and not as an array:

```
var fList = {
add: function(a, b){
    console.log("Addition: " + (a + b))
},

sub: function(a, b){
    console.log("Subtraction: " + (a - b))
},

multi: function(a, b){
    console.log("Multiplication: " + (a * b))
},

div: function(a, b){
    console.log("Division: " + (a / b))
},
}
```

Comment: He wants an array that calls the functions with specific arguments.

Comment: Probably true - I like this way better :)

Answer (score 0):

The error message says it all. fList[0] is not a function - you have defined it as add(1, 1) which would probably be undefined since you don't return anything from add(). What you want is something along the lines of:

```
var add = function(a, b) {
  return a + b;
};

// (...)

var fList = [add, ...];

// (...)
```

And then inside the loop you would:

```
fList[i](1, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You might think about reworking your code to something more like...

```
var fList = [
    { method: add, args: [1,1] },
    { method: sub, args: [1,1] },
    { method: muti, args: [1,1] },
    { method: div, args: [1,1]
}];

for (var i = 0; i < fList.length; i++){
window.apply(null, fList[i].method, fList[i].args);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're making an array of the return values, not an array of functions. Use:

```
var fList = [
    function() { add(1,1); },
    function() { sub(1,1); },
    function() { multi(1,1); },
    function() { div(1,1); }
];
```

You can add to `fList` dynamically with something like this:

```
flist.push(function() { add(2, 3); });
```

Comment: Thanks Barmar, but once more doubt. How to add the function list dynamically to the fList? I have an json with one propery with add(1,1). While processing the json i need to add this propery to fList and at final ill process this list to call the function.

Comment: How are you getting `add(1,1)` in JSON? JSON can only represent arrays, objects, numbers, and strings.

Comment: sorry,it not JSON. its an object. While processing that i am dynamically assign the argument and add to fList to process at last

Comment: You need to show the code you're working on, it's hard to picture it. But I suspect you just need to use closures.

Comment: I added something to the answer, maybe that will help.

Comment: Thanks, its works well for me. I haven't think to push the function to array. Thanks once again !!!